# Why do OCaml binaries crash on Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion)?

Tags: macos, ocaml, osx-mountain-lion

OCaml programs which worked perfectly on Lion fail on Mountain Lion, segfaulting on startup in OCaml runtime code:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: 13 at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x00007fff908e1f88 in large_malloc ()
```

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a widespread problem with the native-compiled (`ocamlopt`) OCaml runtime when backtraces are enabled which is new to Mountain Lion. This same crash affects the startup of *any* OCaml binaries which are:

- [Native compiled](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual025.html) (as opposed to bytecode)
- Run with backtraces enabled (e.g. via `OCAMLRUNPARAM=b`)

This even includes parts of the OCaml compiler toolchain, itself, which will suddenly stop working after an upgrade to 10.8.

This still affects the OCaml SVN trunk (4.01.dev) [as of 2012-07-19](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.caml.general/55354).

The workaround is to disabled backtraces when working with native compiled binaries (unset `OCAMLRUNPARAM`, or remove `b` from your parameter string).

*update*:
The underlying bug appears to be due to insufficient stack alignment in the OCaml runtime implementation. Since the originally post, this is now being tracked and fixed [on the OCaml bug tracker](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5700). For now, however, the workaround remains the only simple choice.

Comment: I don't think you'll get any answer here. Follow things there http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5700

Comment: You're right. I've added a reference to and explanation of the bug as it currently stands. I still think keeping the workaround public is useful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem *may* be solved, there's an explanation and a patch [here](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5700#c7871) in OCaml's bugtracker.